# How to delete row from database on button click wpf c# sql

Tags: c#, sql, .net, wpf

Good Afternoon, I am trying to delete a row from both the datatable and the database. I can currently delete a row from the data table on the front end of my c# application. When I click the delete button I need the row to be deleted from the database as well. The problem I am having is that I do not know how to access the actual elements in each row. When I Console.WriteLine the row, the output is System.Data.DataRowView. My intention is if I can access the elements of the data row, I can write a sql statement to delete the row based on row id. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

MainWindow.xaml

```
Window x:Class="BagRoom.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BagRoom"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Bag Room Lookup" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="target" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="270,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
        <DataGrid Name="bagRoomGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="300" Margin="0,119,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="792">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!-- ... -->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="delete" Content="Delete" Click="DeleteRow"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Click="showTable" Content="Show Table" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Click="Window_Loaded" Content="Lookup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="525,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button Click="addPlayer" Content="Add Player" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="345,80,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
//prints table to main window
        private void showTable(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from players", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                bagRoomGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                bagRoomGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                bagRoomGrid.CanUserAddRows = false;
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

private void DeleteRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
            {
                conn.Open();

                //Code to delete the row from the database

                conn.Close();
            }
                DataRowView row = (DataRowView)bagRoomGrid.SelectedItem;
                dt.Rows.Remove(row.Row);

        }
```

Comment: You are using a SQL Server so the documentation is here.  It is the same string you would use in c# : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @jdweng I believe i need to get the elements from the row in c# before I can delete them from the database

Comment: You usually delete using a Where and delete one ID at a time. So yes you may first need to query database to get the IDs.

Comment: @jdweng yes, so do you know how to access the elements in the row so it does not return with System.Data.DataRowView?

Comment: See following.  The reader is an array so you can access columns by index or name : reader[index or string] : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: @jdweng the tutorial prints back all the rows in the table, I only need the particular row that I click on. Each row in the table has its own delete button. When I click the delete button, I need the information from only that row, not all of the rows.

Comment: The datatable dt has an AcceptChange method.  So if you delete the row from the table you also write the change to the database.  The row index of the DGV is the same as the row index of the DataTable.  So if you click on the DGV row and get the row number in the click event you can then delete the same index of dt.  You also need a commandbuilder.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Answer (score -1):

The "Id" is a primary key column in the database table.

```
    private void DeleteRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)bagRoomGrid.SelectedItem;
        row.Delete();

        int rowsAffected;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE Team WHERE Id = " + row["Id"], conn);
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        if (rowsAffected > 0)
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        else
            dt.RejectChanges();
    }
```